# overflow и скроллы

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я выставил `html {min-width: 320px}` но при уменьшении окна меньше 320px элементы просто уходят за пределы. Не беда, подумал я, и выставил `html {overflow: auto}` и тут начались интересности...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно скролл по высоте ушел под фиксированный элемент. Мне надо, чтобы при достижении минимальной ширины контент перестал ужиматься и появился горизонтальный скролл. Подскажите как это сделать

Comment: 1. Покажите ваш код, а не скрины.
2. Какой результат вы ожидаете получить от min-width: 320px; ?

Comment: Я хочу чтобы при сужении окна меньше установленного 320px появился горизонтальный скролл.

Comment: добавьте [mcve]